# Creating date_trunc index via Hibernate 4.3.5 / JPA 2.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, indexing, annotations

I want to create index like this below:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_foo_req_date
ON foo
USING btree
(date_trunc('day'::text, req_date));
```

How/Can I create it via java hibernate annotations?

I have already read about `@Index` annotation to use it like:

```
@Table(name = "foo", indexes = { @Index(name = "idx_foo_req_date", columnList = "req_date") })
```

but it will create smth like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_foo_req_date
ON foo
USING btree
(req_date);
```

**UPDATE:**

I thought maybe it is pretty flexible and simple and i have tried:

```
@Table(name = "foo", indexes = { @Index(name = "idx_foo_req_date", columnList = "date_trunc('day'::text, req_date)") })
```

However `org.hibernate.AnnotationException` has been thrown, complaining about columns in `columnList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate uses the JPA [`@Index`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Index.html) annotation which doesn't support function-based indexes.

You'd better use Flyway and keep your schema migration in incremental scripts.